# Bokeh: Plotting labels directly above circles of different sizes

Tags: python, bokeh

I am plotting circles of different sizes, relative to the average size (based on a certain circles "score" relative to the average "score")

The circles look good, but I've been struggling to get labels above the circles. When I did manage to get them looking decent, zooming in (which is a feature I want) would allow circle sizes to adjust but the labels wouldn't move and would be left behind.
[This example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/elements.html) was helpful initially, but since the dots are of fixed size and there is no zoom function, it doesn't account for the issues I'm having.

Using the above example, if I know the size of a circle then how can I move the y coordinate of the label to right above the circle?

Answer (score 1):

From the example you linked to:

```
p.text(elements["atomic mass"],
       elements["density"]+0.3,   # The 0.3 adjusts the y coord for the dot size.
       text=elements["symbol"],
       text_color="#333333",
       text_align="center",
       text_font_size="10pt")
```

If you had a column `elements["radius"]` that contained the radius of the dots, you could change `elements["density"]+0.3` to `elements["density"] + elements["radius"]`

Can't help with the zooming though.

Comment: I managed to get a fix like that, but zooming is the biggest issue. I'm surprised bokeh has no built in functionality for labeling glyphs instead of having to generate independent text glyphs.